# Create a new text file with the name and the content of others

Tags: awk

I have several .seq files containing text.
I want to get a single text file containing :

```
name_of_the_seq_file1
contents of file 1
name_of_the_seq_file2
contents of file 1
name_of_the_seq_file3
contents of file 3
```

...

All the files are on the same directory.
It´s possible with awk or similar?? thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can be empty files then you need:

with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}1' *.seq
```

with other awks (untested):

```
awk '
FNR==1 {
    for (++ARGIND;ARGV[ARGIND]!=FILENAME;ARGIND++) {
        print ARGV[ARGIND]
    }
    print FILENAME
}
{ print }
END {
    for (++ARGIND;ARGIND in ARGV;ARGIND++) {
        print ARGV[ARGIND]
    }
}' *.seq
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME}1' *.seq
```

`FNR` is the record number (which is the line number by default) of the current input file. Each time awk starts to handle another file `FNR==1`, in this case the current filename get's printed trough `{print FILENAME}`.

The trailing `1` is an awk idiom. It always evaluates to true, which makes `awk` print all lines of input.

**Note:**

The above solution works only as long as you have no empty files in that folder. Check [Ed Morton's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479908/171318) which points this out.

Comment: hard to be shorter and more efficient with awk

Comment: just be aware that'll fail if there's an empty file. For the OP: is that possible? If so, Better to use GNU awks BEGINFILE than FNR==1 if possible.

Comment: @Manu Górriz Uh! I would have expected that you EdMorten's answer. It works always correct, mine only if no empty files are in that folder

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lpe 'print $ARGV if $. == 1; close(ARGV) if eof' *.seq`

`$.` is the line number
`$ARGV` is the name of the current file
`close(ARGV) if eof` resets the line number at the end of each file